# How is made link like this www.facebook.com/Lukavyi?

Tags: php, facebook, apache, hyperlink

How to make link like www.facebook.com/Lukavyi ?
Must every user have separate php file to have such link? I know, that you can somehow change url with apache, but is link being changed back, when user clicks on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with Apache's `mod_rewrite` URL rewrite engine. You can specify a URL pattern and direct all requests to a page or PHP script of your liking.

It works by creating a `.htaccess` file and setting the rules in there. For example:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^users/(.*)$ users.php?username=$1
```

The first two rows make sure the rewrite engine is enabled, and the third one orders all incoming requests for addresses like `/users/MyUserName` to be redirected internally to `users.php?username=MyUserName`. The user will not see the final address, only the "clean" version.

If you don't want the `users/` part in the URL and instead want `yoursite.com/MyUserName` to work instead, you'll have to create a [front controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern) that will handle all incoming requests.

Answer (score 0):

By using .htaccess and [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) you can handle this.

For example:

You want every user to have it's own URL like `www.example.com/user/UserName`
but want your server to call `www.example.com/user.php?name=UserName` you create a .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ /user.php?name=$1 [L]
```

If you get an error or it doesn't work, try adding this code on top of the .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

Adding the `[L]` in your .htaccess will prevent your browser from redirecting to `user.php?name=UserName` and still shows `/user/Username` but `/user.php?name=UserName` is used. Using `[R]` will redirect.